# Is CUDA Toolkit package contains newest NVidia driver?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, toolkit

Is CUDA Toolkit package (Local Installer) contains newest NVidia standard driver? Standard I mean most popular. 
For example driver for geforce family like 347.88?

Comment: CUDA installers typically contain the *minimum* driver version required by the toolkit in the installer, not the *latest* CUDA driver. Depending on your GPU, in particular when that GPU started shipping after the CUDA version in the installer went final, you may have to install the latest driver package separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The cuda toolkit installers are a snapshot in time.  They contain a reasonably current driver *at that time*, but as time goes by, newer drivers are released, and these don't automatically appear in a given toolkit installer.